# java.exe finished with non-exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I tried to run my application, I got the following error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have tried searching through several forums, but most solutions related to this issue seems to be very situational and none of the solutions worked for me.

Shown below are the information in my messages gradle build:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:compileLint
:libraries:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:libraries:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libraries:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:tess-two:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers136Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta114Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics255Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore238Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsNdk112Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComProlificinteractiveMaterialCalendarview070Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareContactManagment1512LibrariesTessTwoUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 38.882 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

From the questions I saw on various forums,the issue regarding to this seems to be caused by the conflict in "build.gradle" file, mostly under dependencies.

I have included my app "build.gradle" file below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:0.7.0'

    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jtar-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6-mod.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:tess-two')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
        androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
        androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
    }


}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

I am unsure of where it went wrong, if there is any suggestion please kindly point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance!!~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced this problems before. You should only include the libraries you're actually using.

Try to clean your project. Removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build.gradle

Or you can try to enable multidex support by:

```
defaultConfig {        
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes, this helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the error logging message, it seems the issue is happened when link your java library. Could you build the project with option like '-i'? Then we can get more information to find which library is broken.